# Distinguish a connection between HTTP and a simple string protocol using Netty

Tags: netty

I'm trying to distinguish a new connection as an HTTP or framer/string based connection using Netty and I want to use the same server port for both. For now I simply look for "GET " etc. in the first line. However, when using a DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder, I keep receiving String contents even when decoders and encoders are replaced with the HTTP ones. I tryed overriding handleUpstream, messageReceived, fireing events and converting lost messages back to channelbuffers etc. but I had no luck. I also tried to implement a single handler that looks into the first received channelbuffer but I am not able to create a working pipeline afterwards.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on [port unification example](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3.2/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/portunification). You don't have to start from scratch, just modify the PortUnificationServerHandler based on your content type or protocol and add your string protocol encoder/decoders there.